# When to stop training with triplet loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using a Siamse neural network to find the encodings of the properties of some inorganic materials. And later compare the encodings to classify if a material falls to a particular category.

Following so called triplet loss is used as the loss function. α here is the enforced margin between the positive and negative pairs.

[image: triplet_loss]

And finally doing `max(triplet_loss, 0.0)` to ensure the positives are closer to the anchor whereas the negatives are further away.

I have set α to 0.2. And following is a snapshot of my training.

[image: loss]

Should I wait for the loss to be 0 to stop the training? How appropriate is it to stop the training before the loss hits 0, say at some loss value of 0.05?

Comment: do you have a validation loss? if no, thats what you need. (there should be two losses for every epoch, one on training, one on validation)

Comment: If you search on the phrase "How to determine model convergence", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.